# Do Visual Studio 2005 testing tools contain tools for mocking?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, mocking

I'm working with VSTS 2005, and while the unit testing tools are fairly straightforward, I'm left wondering if there is any sort of support for mocking. I'd hate to have to do the mocking manually, because that leads to a lot of (mostly generated) boilerplate code.

I have an edict from The Powers That Be, that a third-party mocking library is not an option. I'm pretty sure that means I'm going to be mocking by hand, but one can always hope. :)

Comment: I tend to think I have it rough because we will go with inferior MS frameworks over better open source solutions, but then I hear things like this. I feel your pain man

Comment: I'm running queries in the background to verify whether or not we have an officially sanctioned mocking library, but I'm sort of doubtful. The edict is against introducing third-party dependencies in general. 

At least we're doing unit testing. :)

Comment: Look, let's face it, The Powers That Be at your establishment are dumbasses for laying this requirement on you.  The solution?  Lie.  Say MS is considering shipping Rhino or MoQ like it's shipping jQuery now.  Keep track of time savings if your tissue of lies ever falls apart, tho!

Comment: No. TPTB are the customer. Trying to subvert their rules would be unethical, not to mention stupid. However, further probings have revealed rumors that a mocking library has been in trial use somewhere, and I'm currently furiously pursuing the possibility of getting the library in use for myself. :)

Comment: It may help in understanding the situation if I add that I'm working on-site with the customer's (very tightly locked down, due to Good and Valid Reasons) equipment and software.

Comment: Yay, we've been greenlighted for the use of the aforementioned library!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no support. You would need to use 3rd party tools for this (oops guess you can't) I mean you will need to do it by hand...sorry to be the bearer of bad news

Comment: Mocking by hand it is, then. Damn. :(

Answer (score 1):

Having a requirement for no third-party libraries in production code may be a reasonable requirement (I would disagree), but forbidding you from using a third-party (and typically free) library for your unit tests seems insane.  Developing your own mocking framework, unless you have requirements that aren't addressed adequately by the existing ones is a waste of valuable developer time.  You ought to spend your time writing tests and code to accomplish your business purposes and a minimal amount of time writing auxiliary software to help you do that.

I know that there are people who feel that all mocking frameworks are evil and you should always hand mock.  That's a different argument with some valid points, though I'm not in that camp.  But if the issue is you can use a MS mocking framework (which doesn't exist, at least yet) or no framework at all, that smacks of stupidity.  A mocking framework used in unit tests won't compromise your production code.

Please feel free to share my response with **The Powers That Be**™

Comment: The question is not of compromising production code, it's of consistency throughout the organization, which is necessary, for certain Good and Valid Reasons. The recommended approach is to write stubs by hand, but I'm going to make the case that unless the interfaces are small, it gets tedious fast.